# Unable to reset element to a vlaue of 0

Tags: javascript

I have the following function here that I am using to reset the value attribute of some buttons to 0:

```
function resetAll() {   
  var getAllButttons = document.getElementsByClassName("click-button");
   for (i = 0; i < getAllButtons.length; i++) { 
   getAllButtons[i].value == 0;
   }
}
```

The function is not doing what I want it to and i'm a bit stuck as to where i've gone wrong..

Comment: `=` and `==` are two different operators.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign it, not compare.

```
function resetAll() {   
  var getAllButttons = document.getElementsByClassName("click-button");
   for (i = 0; i < getAllButtons.length; i++) { 
   // getAllButtons[i].value == 0; // Here you're comparing it
      getAllButtons[i].value = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but its still not changing the value to 0...